# Remove/deactivate Ruby/Rails implicit conversions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, implicit-conversion

Is there a way to remove/deactivate/monkey patch implicit conversions in Ruby/Rails ?

I'm tired of bugs generated by code like this :

```
t = Time.now
t + 3600 == t + 3600.seconds
```

but

```
dt = DateTime.now 
dt + 3600 == dt + 3600.days #(why it's days here and not seconds as with Time ?)
```

Depending of the date type in the addition (or substraction), the result is different because the Integer is implicitly converted to some seconds in case of a Time, and days in case of DateTime.

**Edit:**

Ok. I have some great answers, here.
Maybe a better way to "correct" this quite not so consistent Ruby behavior is to raise an exception if someone try to add a Integer/Fixnum to a Date/Time.
Only Durations should be accepted, don't you think so ?

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: What? None of these statements will be `true` because each generated `now` will be off by milliseconds.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I correct the question

Comment: **Changing the functionality of a core library for any language with monkey patching is dangerous.** You are begging for complications down the road, whether it's yourself or a new developer that is baffled when `DateTime` doesn't work how it should.

Comment: @Mike Agree but I really hate this behavior. IMHO it's not a consistent behavior !

Comment: Despite my answer, I do agree with @Mike, but I found it interesting to extend and write my own behaviour for `+`.

Comment: The solution to raise an exception when the passed type is wrong is not so dangerous

Comment: but it does not work at all. Ahah. My RSpec tests does not launch at all !

Comment: Make sure your rspec tests are including your overrides. Don't forget the exception can still be dangerous because there may be external libraries that depend on adding a `Fixnum` to `Time` objects, and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Warning:** Monkey patching core Ruby functionality can be dangerous, especially in this case since many developers have an expectation of what behaviour `Time` and `Date` objects have when working with `+` and `Fixnum`s. If you're rolling your own solution with **no known libraries** that depend on this expected behaviour, you could utilize this answer. Otherwise, you're entering a world of hurt with unknown edge cases caused by inaccurate objects or random unwanted exceptions.

This is actually behaviour of the `Date` object vs. the behaviour a `Time` object of the core Ruby library. A [`DateTime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) object is an extension of [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html), and Rails just [extends it a bit further](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html).

Here is the [method reference for `Date#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2B), which states:

> Returns a date object pointing other days after self. The other should be a numeric value. If the other is flonum, assumes its precision is at most nanosecond.

Whereas the [method reference for `Time#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Time.html#method-i-2B) behaves differently:

> Adds some number of seconds (possibly fractional) to time and returns that value as a new `Time` object.

Both of these behaviours are Ruby core and library methods written in C, however it is possible to monkey patch this core behaviour in Ruby. For example, to monkey patch `DateTime` to behave with seconds when adding a `Fixnum` to it:

```
class DateTime
  def +(num)
    num = num.to_f / (3600*24) if num.class == Fixnum
    super(num)
  end
end
```

Demo:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-14:/vagrant$ irb
2.1.2 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
2.1.2 :002 > class DateTime
2.1.2 :003?>   def +(num)
2.1.2 :004?>     num = num.to_f / (3600*24) if num.class == Fixnum
2.1.2 :005?>     super(num)
2.1.2 :006?>     end
2.1.2 :007?>   end
 => :+ 
2.1.2 :008 > test = DateTime.now
 => #<DateTime: 2015-11-25T12:09:18-05:00 ((2457352j,61758s,869355861n),-18000s,2299161j)> 
2.1.2 :009 > test + 1
 => #<DateTime: 2015-11-25T12:09:19-05:00 ((2457352j,61759s,869355861n),-18000s,2299161j)>
```

To address your edit, for what you want it would be the same approach. Simply override the classes and raise the exception if the detected parameter is a `Fixnum`:

```
class Time
  def +(num)
    raise TypeError.new("No implicit conversion of Fixnum into Time") if num.class == Fixnum
    super(num)
  end
end

class Date
  def +(num)
    raise TypeError.new("No implicit conversion of Fixnum into Date") if num.class == Fixnum
    super(num)
  end
end

class DateTime
  def +(num)
    raise TypeError.new("No implicit conversion of Fixnum into DateTime") if num.class == Fixnum
    super(num)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To make `Date`/`DateTime` classes to add seconds instead of days in rails:

```
class Date
  def plus_with_duration other
    if ActiveSupport::Duration === other
      other.since self
    else
      plus_without_duration(other.to_f / (24 * 60 * 60).to_f)
    end
  end
  alias_method :+, :plus_with_duration
end
```

To find a method to monkeypatch:

```
DateTime.instance_method(:+).source_location
```